# ZeroMQ broker direct message

Tags: c++, sockets, zeromq, broker

I'm developing a distributed application using ZeroMQ. I want to implement a broker to pass messages in a centralized host.

Imagine serveral clients requesting something, to a given server. The [example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#A-Load-Balancing-Message-Broker) in the ZeroMQ guide, several clients, request for something to the server and some not busy worker, does the work and replies the request.

I need the request to be directed. I mean, I want that server 5 (for instance), do the job. This using a broker in the middle to centralize the comunication in a single host.

Any idea?

**EDIT**

I drew a picture: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1kyh6agIG_3FsllPURSjJFTHGjv-Yg92mfOiTmCdEsO8/edit?usp=sharing
[image: communication example]

The difference (I think) between my case2 and the load balancing broker example in the guide is that the brokers assigns a request to the first free worker. I need to do a request to a specific server. I hope now it is clear.

**EDIT2**

Even more clear. I need [this](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Shared-Queue-DEALER-and-ROUTER-sockets) exactly example. But I can't see how a client requests to a specific server. I run the example, but all request are replied by the first non busy server.

Comment: Can you draw a picture of what you're looking for?  Can you explain why or how the examples or patterns in chapter 4 won't work for you?  Start with the example you linked, and tell us why it won't work for your needs.

Comment: @Jason, imagine the simplest REQ_REP. 1 client asking to 1 server uisng 1 tcp port. Now, I need n1 clients, asking to n2 servers, but using 1 port. Which is the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!!

This is exactly what I need. http://arslan.io/zeromq-request-slash-reply-to-a-specific-server-via-router-router-broker-in-go

I hope it helps someone

Comment: the link is dead and I desperately need to know it, can you share if you have it. gmate.sunny@gmail.com